# Is returning true or throwing an exception good or bad code practice?

Tags: design-patterns, exceptions, clean-code

I am focusing on learning better design and wondered if this code is good or an anti-pattern? The function `Validate()` returns true if the data is correct, else it will throw an exception with a message to display in a popup.

Another way could have been to return a string and treat empty string as validated, but I don't see that as much cleaner.

```
try
{
    if (await Validate(data))
    {
        //logic
        success = true
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   message = e.Message;
   success = false;
}

return new GenericResponse(success, data, message);
```

Comment: What will it mean when `Validate` returns false? Will this be a program error?

Comment: The function did never return false but threw an exception in that case. But i liked the approach using out instead I then discovered that async cant use out, my solution was to pass Active<string> instead and just have an implicit function that assigns the error message

Comment: So you say `Validate` should never return false, and when it would, it would be a program error, yes? If that's correct, you could simply make `Validate` a void function.

Comment: @proeng, if it's async (and presumably we are talking C# here), it could return `Task<(bool, string)>`. As before, when false, the string contains the error message.

Comment: @DavidArno: or simply a `Task<string>` , with the convention of using null or the empty string if no error occured.

Comment: Well  i used Action<string> instead for out, this way i could use the function inline an if check. Using null or empty string i would not consider good practice cause it require outside knowlede and create dependancies.

Comment: That works. . @DocBrown that’s an equally valid approach. It becomes a matter of preferred style at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either returning `true` or throwing an exception is an unusual way of indicating success or failure. It's not an anti-pattern, but it's not good practice either. Until I read the description of what happens properly, my immediate thought was that you weren't handling `Validate` returning `false`. It therefore breaks the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

A better approach would be to use the try pattern, eg for a language that uses `out` parameters you might have something like:

```
bool TryValidate(SomeType data, out string failureMessage);
```

where the return value is true for success and false for failure. When false, `failureMessage` contains the reason it fails (and it's undefined when the return is true).

Depending on the language you are using, you could use a tuple or even an `Either<bool, string>` union to return the data. Whichever method is used though, the principle of the pattern is `true/false` with a message when `false` is returned.

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a better approach. I was using try catch cause the logic did calls that required exception handling, so i thought might aswell piggyback. But i see now this way is more clear.

Comment: IMO using exceptions for flow control is a bad practice and should be considered as an anti pattern.

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra, the moment you put a `try/catch` in your code, you are using exceptions for control flow.

Comment: @DavidArno that way we can write code without conditionals. Seriously, an exception path is different from normal flow of the program. Mixing them up is a bad idea. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

This is the very worst kind of Exception "swallowing".

```
try
{
   . . . 
catch (Exception e)
{
   // Do nothing useful 
}
```

The **calling code** knows that the function failed - it returned false - but can do nothing whatever about that failure.
If it had been thrown an Exception, it might have been able to take some more useful, corrective action.  That's how Structured Exception Handling is *supposed* to work.
But throwing an Exception for each and every Validation error is expensive.

**You** know that the function failed - it returned false, which made the application behave a certain way - but have *no idea why* it did so and, therefore, *no idea* how to go about *fixing* it!
You should, at the very least, capture and record the Exception rather than making it "magically" *disappear*.

> Another way could have been to return a string and treat empty string as validated, but I don't see that much cleaner.

Actually, it *is* and it's a very common model in Validation.
You ask your method to validate something and it returns you a message indicating what, if anything, is wrong with it.  That's a far more "useful" value than just "Yes or No".

Comment: The example code in the question very clearly shows that the exception message is captured and returned. Your comments about not returning such information being bad is correct but it is unrelated to this question.

Comment: I do think your comment where helpful in showing why my first approach is not good design. I was throwing the messages using exception, but i learned now it is expensive and not intuitive. So having a function that return true or false, aswell as the message seems clearer.